# excel macros - line chart loses year axis values and chart title

Tags: excel, macros

I am recording a macro using Excel 2013 to create a line chart.

I have one column with years and an adjacent column with population values. The column headings are "Year" and "Population" respectively.

The line chart looks good.

When I run the macro, the chart title (Population) is striped out. Additionally the year values (x axis) are replaced with a number series, 1 . . . onwards

How do I have the macro retain the year values and the chart title (Population)?

Thanks!

This is my recorded Macro

```
Range("A1:B29").Select 
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized 
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkers).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("compilation!$A$1:$B$29")
```

This is an example of what I want the final graph to look like when I run the macro.

[image: Final Product]

Comment: This could be the difference between a line chart and a scatter plot.  IF I recall correctly line plots are just the Y values equally spaced along the X axis.  Also you could post your recorded macro and people may be able to help you edit it. Maybe a screen shot of what you want and one of what you are getting?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.
Here is the macro:
    Range("A1:B29").Select
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLineMarkers).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("compilation!$A$1:$B$29") 
[Image of desired:](http://mmnkltd.com/macro-screenshot.jpg).

Comment: just as an aside, in the future if you have information to add to the question, click on the edit link at the bottom of the question and above the comments.  It will allow you to do thing like add your macro and add your screen shot, or even reword your question.  I have already gone back and added the graph and code for you.  Just need to wait for those edits to be approved since I did them instead of you.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I had trouble getting the FTP process to work to see the image. So there was a big time lag.
Hopefully I'm not missing the point, missing the location of the comment button. 
I look forward to seeing more. Thanks again.

Comment: no worries on that.  for future reference alt+printscreen will capture your active window in MS Windows.  You can then turn around and go to a site like [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and in the top left corner click the blue button to upload.  A window will come up and then hit CTRL+V and it will upload your screen shot to the web.  The site will allow you to crop you image.   And then you can use direct link for embedding in questions...I am off topic now...back to getting your title!  BTW, when you run your macro do you now get two line on your graph instead of 1?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your last line of your macro

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=compilation!$A$2:$A$29"
```

That should get you your year back along the bottom.

```
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "=compilation!R1C2"
```

That will set your Title for you.  However you still need your Primary Horizontal Title so why dont we throw in this tid bit of random code:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
Selection.Caption = "=compilation!R1C1"
```

now the only outstanding issue is if you are generating 1 or 2 lines in your graph.

To get rid of the second line (technically the first since its really series 1) we have two choices.

Choice 1 is to select it with the code and delete it.  I am going to opt for choice 2 though.  Choice 2 is to never add it in the first place!

So to start with eliminate your first line of your Macro.  When the graph is initially created, it will be created as a blank slate as there is no preselected data.  So what we need to do is change 1 lettre in the line of your macro where you define the Source. (4th line of your posted code) and we are going to change the starting cell reference from $A$1 to $B$1.  If the graph only has one column of data to work with for points then there can only be one series.  So that line will look like the following in the end:

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("compilation!$B$1:$B$29")
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully to add the years and to fix the chart title. Yes, two lines are being generated. The Population line is great. The year line is there as well. How to keep that from displaying? Thanks again.
[Image](http://mmnkltd.com/macro-screenshot_02.jpg)

Comment: So there you have a solution.  I am personally strongly adverse Line Graphs for the most part.  I almost always favour XY scatter plots.  If you do not under the difference, add 50 or a 100 years to your last year in your data.  I would expect if there was that much of a jump in the last year and every other year was just a jump of 1 year, there would be a big gap between the last point and the second last point.  An XY scatter plot will do that.  A line plot does not.

Comment: Hi Ed, Using the scatter chart will work really well.
Thank you for all the help.